# How to assume a table prefix on a entire MySQL script?

Tags: mysql, sql, prefix

I have a script to run in my database.
But the problem is this script assume the tables have no prefix on it and all databases have a prefix (let call it **prefix_**).

Is there a command or a way to MySQL try to run

```
INSERT INTO prefix_mytable ...
```

instead of

```
INSERT INTO mytable...
```

for all of sql queries at the script (UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE)?

Comment: Nope, your script will have to account for that. MySQL only knows the table name it has (the prefixed one)

Comment: Michael, if we can some internal option in mysql like ASSUME_GLOBAL_PREFIX and we set it as **prefix_** this should work. But is there a option for that? =/

Comment: My point is that there is no such option in MySQL I have ever encountered in documentation. I hope someone proves me wrong in the answers below, because I agree that would be useful. If you tell us how you're running the script, maybe someone will have a wizard hack suggestion.

Comment: I need to run a script for magento translation (extra pack for it). But the problem, as I related, the script didn't find the tables because the server that I hosted the installation puts a prefix on the tables...

Comment: I think you'll need to modify the script then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way in MySQL to automatically prefix tables in the way you're describing.  @MichaelBerkowski is correct.

The best I can suggest is that you create a second database with updateable views, using unprefixed names, as front-ends to your prefixed table names.

Here's an example:

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE test;
mysql> CREATE TABLE test.prefix_mytable (id INT PRIMARY KEY, x VARCHAR(20));
mysql> CREATE DATABASE test2;
mysql> CREATE VIEW test2.mytable AS SELECT * FROM test.prefix_mytable;
```

Now you can insert using the unprefixed names:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO test2.mytable (id, x) VALUES (123, 'abc');
```

And to verify that the data was inserted into your original table:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test.prefix_mytable;
```

Once you do that, you can run your SQL script against database `test2` and all the INSERTs should get to your original tables all right.

If you have a lot of tables you need to create views for, you can automate the creation of the CREATE VIEW statements:

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT('CREATE VIEW test2.', REPLACE(TABLE_NAME, 'prefix_', ''), 
  ' AS SELECT * FROM test.', TABLE_NAME, ';') AS _sql 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='test' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'prefix\_%';
```

Comment: Effective. Insane, but effective.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, LOL!  Thanks!  Every problem is solvable -- it's just a matter of how many hoops one has to jump through. :-)

Comment: Interesting solution. But it looks like a bad MySQL limitation, if we have a internal var called prefix this could be very easy^^

Comment: @GarouDan, can you name any other RDBMS product that supports this idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the guide to replace WordPress table prefix from wp_ to a different, like this you can update any mysql table. [How to rename WordPress tables prefix?](http://www.w3update.com/cms/wordpress/how-to-rename-wordpress-tables-prefix.html)

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers, to get more understanding how to **not** answer. Namely: "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question": **barely more than a link to an external site**